# シェルスクリプトで、 ruby でいう ensure がやりたい

Tags: bash, shellscript

シェルスクリプトで、何が起ころうが基本的にスクリプトが終了する直前に実行してほしいコマンドがあるとします。今の具体的な想定としては、 mktemp で作ったディレクトリの削除です。

シェルスクリプトは、通常であれば上から順番にコマンドを実行していき、最後に終了しますが、ぱっと思いつくかぎりでも、以下のケースで (スクリプトの途中で) 終了します。

- exit コマンドの実行
- sigint, sigterm などのシグナルの受信

これらの場合でも、適切に終了処理を実行してくれるシェルスクリプトは記述できますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[trap](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-trap) で `EXIT` のハンドラを書けばよいと思います。次のようなスクリプトでテストしてみてください。

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
trap "rm -rf $TMPDIR" EXIT
echo "Created $TMPDIR"
read a
```

実行すると `Created /tmp/tmp.d3EITJailU` のようにテンポラリディレクトリを表示して入力待ちになります。 <kbd>ENTER</kbd> を押して正常終了したり <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> で止めたりするとそのディレクトリは消されます。

Comment: 各シグナル(?) に対してハンドラをひとつ設定できる機能だと理解しました。

Comment: EXIT (または 0) は bash 独自の特殊な trap シグナル指定方法で、理由の如何にかかわらず、プログラムが終了する場合に（可能であれば）trap が実行されます。正常終了時にも実行されるので、mktemp 等で作った一時ファイルを確実に消す場合には便利ですね。

Comment: 「EXIT (または 0) は bash 独自」ではありません。POSIX 互換 sh なら使えます。
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/trap.html

Answer (score 1):

> sigint, sigterm などのシグナルの受信

実際の所、`SIGKILL` だけは `trap` による対応ができません。

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo Exit' EXIT
kill -HUP $$
```

`SIGHUP` の場合は、

```
$ ./trap.sh
Exit
Hangup
```

となりますが、`kill -KILL $$` にすると以下の様になります。

```
$ ./trap.sh
Killed
```

まぁ、`SIGKILL` は特別扱いで構わないのかもしれませんが、`SIGKILL` が発行された場合でもアクションを行いたい場合もあるかもしれません。

Linux 系 OS には inotify というファイルシステムに発生するイベント(`open(2), close(2)`, etc.)をフックする機構があります。シェルスクリプトが実行されて、何らかの原因(正常終了を含む)でシェルプロセスが終了する際にはそのスクリプトファイルをクローズします。そのクローズイベントを拾ってアクションを実行します。

```
#!/bin/bash
temp=$(mktemp)
nohup sh -c "inotifywait -qq -e close \"$0\" && rm -f $temp" &>/dev/null &
echo "Created $temp"
read a

$ ./notify.sh
Created /tmp/tmp.JfL9ZTrmv3

# 別の端末で以下を実行
$ pkill -KILL notify.sh

# notify.sh を実行した端末
$ ./notify.sh
Created /tmp/tmp.JfL9ZTrmv3
Killed

$ ls /tmp/tmp.JfL9ZTrmv3
ls: cannot access '/tmp/tmp.JfL9ZTrmv3': No such file or directory
```

もっとも、`inotifywait` を別プロセスで起動するので、そちらに `SIGKILL` を発行されてしまうとどうにもなりませんが。